# finding the inverse function $f(x) = x^5+ x^3 + x$, then find what is $f^{-1}(3)$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

if $f(x) = x^5+ x^3 + x$, then $f^{-1}(3) = ?$

I TRIED to do it, and I got this answer : 3/91 . I don't know if it is correct or not?

I tried to do this work like this: 
$$ y = x^5+x^3+x\\
y = x(x^4+x^2+1)\\
y/(x^4+x^2+1) = x\\
y = x/(x^4+x^2+1)\\
f^{-1}(x)= x/(x^4+x^2+1)\\
f^{-1}(3)=3/91$$

Comment: What is $f(1)$? Also notice that $f'(x)\gt0$.

Comment: Your fourth step is wrong. You go from $\frac{y}{x^4+x^2+1} = x$ to $y = \frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1}$, i.e., moved the denominator from one side to the other; you would have had to **multiply through** by $x^4+x^2+1$, and that would just have given you back your second line.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin how would i do it then?

Comment: P.S. You'll have a **very** hard time finding an analytic formula for $f^{-1}$. But you aren't supposed to find one. You can use calculus to verify that $f$ is one-to-one, and then **eyeball** a number that $f$ maps to $3$, to get the value of $f^{-1}(3)$. You don't need to figure out how to invert *every* value, just $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=y(x)$ is an inverse function.

Thus, $y^5+y^3+y=3,$ which since $y^5+y^3+y$ increases, gives $y=1$ and $f^{-1}(3)=1.$

Comment: How are your $y$ and $f$ (or $f^{-1}$) related to $x$ and $f$ from the original post?

Comment: I just used the definition of inversed functions. You can see it in the net or I'll come back to the home and I'll write this definition.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it's just $y=f^{-1}(3)$ and thus $3=f(f^{-1}(3))=f(y)=y^5+y^3+y$... I think that I missed that one step.

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais Indeed, $f(f^{-1}(3))=3$ because for all $x$ from the domain of $f^{-1}$ we have $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, but $f^{-1}(3)=f^{-1}(f(1))=1.$

Comment: Thanks, but that's clear. The step missing in my mind was that you replaced $x$ from the definition of $f(x)$ with $y=f^{-1}(3)$, the desired value. The confusing thing was that you were looking at the problem from the $y$-axis (assuming that we already have an inverse function and solving an equation concerning the image of $f^{-1}$) while all other answerers (including me) solved an equation of the form $f(x)=3$, looking at the problem from the $x$-axis. :-)

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais Now I understand you. I just love to assume that the argument of any function is $x$. I think it's more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)-3 = x^5+x^3+x-3 = (x-1)(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+3) = 0$
$\Leftrightarrow x=1 \quad \lor \quad x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+3 = 0$

Since $f'(x) = 5x^4 + 3x^2 + 1 \ge 1 > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $f$ is strictly monotone increasing, thus $x=1$ must be the only (real) solution.